# back-end to database approach

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm using asp.net core as back-end and mySQL as database.
I got to a point where I'm getting arrays from the front-end to insert into my database.
My question is: Should I iterate on the array and send multiple requests to database, or is it more "cheap" to send the data as strings and decompose the data in the database?

example:

```
let array = [{id: 1, name: "a"},{id:2, name:"b"}];
```

option 1:

```
//for each data in array -> send insert query
```

option 2:

```
//create two string
let ids = "1,2";
let names = "a,b";

//send 1 request to database, 
//use stored procedure with methods like `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `INSTR` to decompose the data from strings.
```

An healthy explanation would be helpful.

Comment: It is always better to avoid multiple round trips to database server. So you can also save multiple records by sending data as xml to database

Comment: @kritikaTalwar I think in my case, sending the data as xml is the best approach. the workplace is strict about using procedures instead of preparing dynamic queries. so creating a global function to create xmls from arrays and a procedure that will handle them is a reasonable approach for me.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL can be helpful here. Create a dynamic query in code to insert all the row in one go into database. You can do that as given below

```
INSERT INTO tab(id,name)
VALUES (1,'a'),
       (2,'b');
```

Comment: maybe I didn't explained myself as I should, but this is the 2nd option. I'm using stored procedures and passing them the stings, then using the query as you said.

Comment: not exactly. you dont need to decompose anything here. In this case two separate rows will be inserted in the table. first row will have id column with value 1 and name column with value 'a' and so on. No further processing is required here.

Comment: oh so you say to create the query dynamically in the back-end? did I understood correctly?

Comment: hmmm OK will be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Entity framework [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro)

Comment: I wish I could but the workplace is very fixed on this... yea I know....